# Sphinx extension - installation of sphinxcontrib-bibtex

Tags: python, macos, python-sphinx, osx-elcapitan

**Osx 10.11.6 El Capitan**

I need help in the installation of sphinxcontrib-bibtex (https://github.com/mcmtroffaes/sphinxcontrib-bibtex).
I tried in many ways, but I could not compile using the make command.

```
➜ thesis_source git:(master) ✗ make html
Running Sphinx v1.6.3
loading translations [es]... done
Extension error:
Could not import extension sphinxcontrib.bibtex (exception: No module named oset)
make: *** [html] Error 1
```

- Osx 10.11.6 El Capitan
- Sphinx 1.7.4
- sphinxcontrib-bibtex 0.4.0
- sphinxcontrib-websupport 1.0.1
- Python 2.7.10
- Python 3.6.4

In conf.py file:

```
extensions = [
'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
'sphinx.ext.doctest',
'sphinx.ext.intersphinx',
'sphinx.ext.todo',
'sphinx.ext.coverage',
'sphinx.ext.mathjax',
'sphinx.ext.ifconfig',
'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
'sphinx.ext.githubpages',
'sphinxcontrib.bibtex']
```

Another information

```
➜ thesis_source git:(master) ✗ pip install sphinxcontrib-bibtex
Requirement already satisfied: sphinxcontrib-bibtex in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.4.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from sphinxcontrib-bibtex) (1.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pybtex-docutils>=0.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from sphinxcontrib-bibtex) (0.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pybtex>=0.20 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from sphinxcontrib-bibtex) (0.21)
Requirement already satisfied: oset>=0.1.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from sphinxcontrib-bibtex) (0.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: Sphinx>=1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from sphinxcontrib-bibtex) (1.7.4)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils>=0.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pybtex-docutils>=0.2.0->sphinxcontrib-bibtex) (0.15b0.dev0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML>=3.01 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pybtex>=0.20->sphinxcontrib-bibtex) (3.12)
Requirement already satisfied: latexcodec>=1.0.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pybtex>=0.20->sphinxcontrib-bibtex) (1.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from oset>=0.1.3->sphinxcontrib-bibtex) (38.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: imagesize in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Sphinx>=1.0->sphinxcontrib-bibtex) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Pygments>=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Sphinx>=1.0->sphinxcontrib-bibtex) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: alabaster<0.8,>=0.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Sphinx>=1.0->sphinxcontrib-bibtex) (0.7.10)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Sphinx>=1.0->sphinxcontrib-bibtex) (2.12.4)
Requirement already satisfied: babel!=2.0,>=1.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Sphinx>=1.0->sphinxcontrib-bibtex) (2.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Sphinx>=1.0->sphinxcontrib-bibtex) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: sphinxcontrib-websupport in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Sphinx>=1.0->sphinxcontrib-bibtex) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: snowballstemmer>=1.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Sphinx>=1.0->sphinxcontrib-bibtex) (1.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Sphinx>=1.0->sphinxcontrib-bibtex) (17.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=0a in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from babel!=2.0,>=1.3->Sphinx>=1.0->sphinxcontrib-bibtex) (2013.7)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.3->Sphinx>=1.0->sphinxcontrib-bibtex) (1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from packaging->Sphinx>=1.0->sphinxcontrib-bibtex) (2.2.0)
```

Comment: Whatever you did to install all these packages is not the correct way, and saying you installed two Python versions smells bad. First open a new shell, and enter `python --version`. Now within a clean project folder (e.g., `mkdir ~/projects/soclean && cd ~/projects/soclean`), for Python 3.6, create a virtual environment `python -m venv env`. Activate it, `source env/bin/activate`. Now `pip install <everything>`. Finally copy over your docs from the messed up environment into `soclean`, and try `make html`.

Comment: Use `pythonX.Y -m pip list` to check where your pip installed the Python modules. Please be aware, that Python2 uses `pip` and Python3 uses `pip3` on most platforms. Even so, you might have different Python3 installations with distinct package lists. You should investigate where `python` and `python3` is pointing to.

Comment: Check first what the location of the executables `which python`, `which pip`, `which python3`, `which pip3` and `which sphinx-build`. It might be that the program `sphinx-build` is not in `/usr/local/` where you have the necessary packages.

Comment: If `python3` points to the right location, you can call sphinx with `python3 -m sphinx` (edit the makefile at the appropriate line to have `SPHINXBUILD = python3 -m sphinx`).